# cannot install browser-sync on macbook

Tags: macos, browser-sync

I'm using the latest macbook air laptop and trying to install browser-sync globally by this command "sudo npm install -g browser-sync" after install node.js and npm succesfully.
but after I tried this command, my terminal shows this error message again and again when I'm trying to install the package repeatly since I cannot find the browser-sync command.
could anyone help me solve this problem? thank you so much in advance!

I have tried to install this package since yesterday and really don't know how it will work. I checked the user/judy/node_modules folder and can find 3 browser-sync related folders, and tried to delete them but still failed to make the command work.

error message
(base) judy@judydeAir node_modules % sudo npm install -g browser-sync
Password:
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.browser-sync-7ZQRhsQ1
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browser-sync' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.browser-sync-7ZQRhsQ1'

my path:
(base) judy@judydeAir node_modules % echo $PATH
/Users/judy/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/judy/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

failed to use browser-sync command:
(base) judy@judydeAir node_modules % browser-sync --version
zsh: command not found: browser-sync

Comment: i'm following coursera course to learn how to build a website actually...didn't expect to face this challenge at the beginning of my study...anyone could help!!! thanks so much!

Comment: I got a very similar problem and got it fixed by setting a $PATH variable by export according to https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/.
Hope you can fix your $PATH setting and continue with the coursera course!